# Add a timestamp to one column when other columns changed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I'm trying to add a timestamp to a column when other cells in the same row are completed or changed.

The below script works if just one column is changed, but not multiple columns.

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Allocation Requests" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 7) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 7);
          nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get it so that if columns E,F,G or H are changed, the timestamp in Column M is updated. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps this will work

```js
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sheet1" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 5) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 8);
          nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
       if( r.getColumn() == 6) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 7);
          nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
       if( r.getColumn() == 7) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 6);
          nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
       if( r.getColumn() == 8) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, 5);
          nextCell.setValue(new Date());
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh change your sheet name-  I have it as sheet1

Comment: Though altering it slightly (as well as the sheet name) does work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
function onEdit() {
      var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      if( s.getName() == "Allocation Requests" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
        var r = s.getActiveCell();
        if( r.getColumn() >= 5 && r.getColumn() <= 8) { //checks the column
           s.getRange(r.getRow(),13).setValue(new Date());
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Though I've now found that this adds an updated timestamp even when I add/delete the timestamp in the timestamp column.

Comment: Indeed that was the case I changed to and from or. This is a little improvement bacause adding or removing columns in the code doesn't require you to copy paste more code for each column